# how to read Json from local file

Tags: javascript, html, json, web

I use inspect to check and it shows as below:
lottie.js:3 Failed to load file:///Users/Downloads/ani/js/data.json: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I dont know how to read Json from a .json file from my local sever?
can anyone help me to solve it?

```js
var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById('Ani'),
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  path: 'js/data.json'
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
  <!--  Meta  -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bodymovin Demo</title>
  <!--  Styles  -->
  <style>
   #Ani{max-width: 800px; margin:0 auto;}
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
  
  <div id="Ani"> </div>
  
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="js/lottie.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `run Json` - JSON is a data interchange format - it does not run, it doesn't even walk!

Comment: I mean....I got some problem to use a web server to load json files locally

Comment: Have you deployed this in some website/webapplication on your local machine? for example IIS or something? If not then try that, and IIS should have full access to your JSON file.

Comment: If you are loading the HTML file with your browser directly from the filesystem then you are not using (or do not have) a "local server".

Comment: I just open it directly on my browser. Is that possible to open it directly?

Comment: It will not. The browser has restrictions in accessing the files from the system, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file with the `file` protocol and you try an Ajax request. That wont work. You better open the file over a server. You can use apache or any webserver? By example if you are familiar with Node you can use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)
 or use [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server).

```
npm install http-server -g
http-server 'path/to/your/project' -o
```

That should open the browser window at: localhost:8080 or other port if `8080` is not free

Comment: is any possibility to loading json without a http get